# What is the meaning of "argv + argc"?

Tags: c++

I'm writing a program that accepts command line arguments and prints them out in alphanumerically sorted order with a custom comparator.

Along the way I got stuck with inserting the command-line arguments in the `std::set` container. Reviewed some similar code online and found something like:

```
std::set<char*, decltype(customComparator)> args (argv, argv+argc, customComparator)
```

**What does the `argv + argc` argument mean/do?**

When I tried inserting the cmd argument like:

```
std::set<char*, decltype(customComparator)> args (argv, customComparator)
```

There's a red squiggly line on the `argv` argument.

Comment: `argv + argv` is equivalent to `std::end(argv)`, while that won't compile.

Comment: This is not a duplicate of [What does `int argc, char *argv[]` mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3024197/what-does-int-argc-char-argv-mean). The question is what `argv+argc` means, not `argv` and `argc` on their own.

Comment: look into "pointer arithmetic" to get an idea why

Comment: thanks @KennyOstrom. I figured it out. It points to the end of the char array

Comment: This is overload (2) of the [std::set constructors](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/set). `argv` and `argv + argc` are the beginning and end of the range, `customComparator` is the comparator, and you're using the default allocator.

Comment: it actually points to the end of the array that contains pointers to `char`, each pointer pointing to an individual argument.

Answer (score 11):

> What is the meaning of "argv + argc"?

`argv + argc` is a pointer that points to the end of the last command line argument(or to the null shown in the diagram below). This is explained below(both graphically and in text form).

The diagram is shown for `argc = 5` :

[image: argv + argc]

##### Explanation

Lets consider the declaration:

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
```

In the above declaration, the type of the second parameter named `argv` is actually a `char**`. That is, `argv` is a *pointer to a pointer to a `char`*. This is because a `char* []` **decays** to a **`char**`** due to **type decay**.

In other words, `argv` is a pointer that points to the first element of an array with elements of type `char*`. Moreover, each element `argv[i]` of the array(with elements of type `char*`) itself point to a character which is the start of a *null terminated* character string. That is, each element `argv[i]` points to the first element of an array with elements of type `char`.

Comment: `NULL` is proper after `argv[4]` in your example to differentiate the `NULL` pointer from the `nul-character`.  (I get it, but you wouldn't want a new user thinking all were the same)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Yes, do you recommend using some other notation? I can add it in my diagram.

Comment: No. I like your diagram, it really helps, the `NULL`/`null` was the only thing that stood out.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Oh, thanks for the appreciation :)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Do you recommend that for the character arrays to which `argv[i]` points that i should replace the last with `'\0'` but let the `null` remain after the `argv[4]` ?

Comment: I would do that. the `null` is subject to different interpretations, but in the context at the end of the string it was clear it meant *nul-character*. but changing to `'\0'` would be more clear.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Done, now there should be no room left for beginners considering them the same.

Comment: You really like `null` instead of `NULL` as the pointer value for the next `argv[]` value after the last argument provided by the user?

Comment: argv+argc is not necessary NULL/null, it is not initialized and dereferenced it will give undefined behaviour.

Comment: No. `argv[]` is `char *[]` (an array of pointers) where the next pointer after the last user provided argument is set `NULL` as a sentinel.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I have changed `null` to `NULL`. My original intention when creating this diagram was that `null` is the same as `NULL` but now that you've mentioned it i have changed it to `NULL` explicitly and `null` in the `char` was to be treated as the null character instead of `NULL`.

Answer (score 6):

The code you're showing uses the iterator based constructor, which receives a `begin` iterator, and a past the `end` iterator.

The thing is, a pointer is also considered an iterator by the STL. The `++ptr` operator works, as well as `ptr != end_ptr` and `*ptr`.

So, if you want to construct an STL container from a C-style collection of objects, it's very well possible to do so. `argv` is the beginning of all the args value(s), and `argv[argc - 1]` is the end. To get a pointer past the end, simply do `argv + argc`.

Comment: "A pointer can very much act like an iterator" feels a bit weird to say. Iterators are defined by the behaviors they exhibit, and a pointer into an array _is_ an iterator, not something different that happens to act similar.

Answer (score 6):

1. This overload of the `std::set` constructor accepts *two iterators* and a comparator. The two iterators should define a *half-open range*. The second iterator points to the end of the range, which for many kinds of ranges, is the *one past the last* element.
2. A pointer is an iterator.
3. If `argv` points to the first element of an array, and `argc` is an integer, then `argv + argc` points to `argc`th element of the same array (starting from zero).
4. Since there are exactly `argc` meaningful elements in the `argv` array, `argv + argc` points *one past the last* meaningful element of the array. (There happens to be another element there, bit it is a null pointer and we are not interested in it).

All in all, the range `[argv, argv + argc)` is exactly the kind of half-open range standard library expects in lots of places.

Comment: What did you mean by *"half-open range"*? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Perhaps that the second iterator is excluded = one past the last element (cf. 1.)? In the mathematical sense of half-open intervals.